# Scraper in Laravel-9

Tags: php, project, laravel-9

Im working for my project where i scrape form different skin websites and you can see which has cheaper skins. So i made my first scraper and it doesnt scrape. Could use some help.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte\Client;

class CsmoneyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://cs.money/market');
        $skins = $crawler->filterXPath('.BuyPage_body__27jeL')->each(function ($node) {
            $name = $node->filterXPath('.market-item__name')->text();
            $price = $node->filterXPath('//div[contains(@class, "styles_price__1m7op")]/span[contains(@class, "price_currency__1RmBq")]')->text();
            $image = $node->filterXPath('//img[@class="BaseCard_image_content__2GmuD"]')->attr('src');
            $float = $node->filterXPath('.csm_ui__text__6542e csm_ui__body_12_regular__6542e CSGODescription_description__3cUg_ large')->eq(0)->text();
            $condition = $node->filterXPath('.market-item__params .param')->eq(1)->text();
            return [
                'name' => $name,
                'price' => $price,
                'image' => $image,
                'float' => $float,
                'condition' => $condition
            ];
        });

        return view('scraper', ['skins' => $skins]);
    }
}
```